# Ignore json varible while sending response in resteasy api

Tags: java, resteasy

I want to ignore null value variables in json response.
tried using fasterxml

```
@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonProperty("response_value")
private String response_value = null;
```

also

```
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonProperty("response_value")
    private String response_value = null;
```

not working.
Is there any other solution??

Comment: You can try to directly configure your `ObjectMapper` instance instead: `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);`

Comment: Make sure that you don't have a mix of Jackson v1 and v2 because they ignore each others annotations

Comment: Also, are you sure that Jackson is even doing the JSON serialization? Perhaps RESTEasy is still doing it?